# how can we handle assets for multiple environment?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Ok so I am going to use react-native-config to make my app having multiple environments. But the project requirements are such as we should be able to export different apps from same codebase for different clients with different bundle id.

We can achieve that using product flavors in android and schemes in iOS side but I don't know how to handle assets/images we have in our js project. For an example, client A has different images and client B has different images, I can definitely show/hide those images based on the .env variables but I don't want those images to get included while building the app for release.

is it possible to use Webpack or babel in such case or any automation script?

What can be the possible solution for this scenario? Feel free to ask me any questions if you didn't understand what I am asking here, sorry in advance for that.

Comment: Hi Sarag, Have you find a solution to your requirements? I am also looking for the same